# Does HoTMaiL or Windows Live ID support OpenID authentication?

Tags: openid, hotmail, windows-live-id

Does Windows Live ID or Hotmail (Passport) support OpenID based authentication?

If yes, what is the endpoint url, and do I have to register my application somewhere to use it?

If no, do they have their own API for 3rd-party authentication?

Answer (score 12):

On the [Windows Live Blog](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_live/b/developer/), there are only two different mentions of Open ID.  Neither of those point to any actual movement on implementing Open ID.

- [Welcome to the Windows Live for Developers Blog](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_live/b/developer/archive/2010/06/16/welcome-to-the-windows-live-for-developers-blog.aspx)
- [Announcing Support for OAuth 2.0](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_live/b/developer/archive/2011/05/04/announcing-support-for-oauth-2-0.aspx)

There is no mention of a working Microsoft provider on the [OpenID Web Site](http://openid.net/get-an-openid/).  Even though Microsoft is [part of the OpenID board](http://www.marketwire.com/press-release/technology-leaders-join-openid-foundation-promote-open-identity-management-on-web-nasdaq-goog-818650.htm), it seems they are only adding OpenID support *within* Microsoft products.

- Windows Azure [has support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg185935.aspx) to authenticate using OpenID - with a non-Microsoft provider.
- Windows Live is [*supposed* to have support](http://openid.net/2008/10/30/microsoft-and-google-announce-openid-support/) to authenticate using OpenID - with a non-Microsoft provider.  Unfortunately, the [announcement link](http://dev.live.com/blogs/devlive/archive/2008/10/27/421.aspx) to the Windows Live developer's blog no longer works, and I can find nothing on the [Windows Live sign-in page](https://login.live.com/login.srf).

There was the [mention](http://lists.openid.net/pipermail/openid-general/2007-November/003729.html) of an experimental OpenID provider from Microsoft back in 2007, but the web site [isn't working](http://www.inkblotpassword.com/).  In addition, there was another experimental OpenID provider for Windows Live, but it was [shut down](http://www.liveside.net/2009/08/28/an-update-for-openid-support-in-windows-live-id/) in 2009.

I believe that with the [death](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/card/archive/2011/02/15/beyond-windows-cardspace.aspx) of Windows CardSpace in February 2011 and the purchase of [Credentica](http://www.networkworld.com/news/2008/030708-microsoft-credentica.html), it sounds like Microsoft is jumping out of the OpenID bandwagon in favor of a proprietary solution.

Comment: Also see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056263/is-windows-live-id-an-openid-provider

Comment: @airmanx86 While that answer is still true, it doesn't cover the answer in any real detail.  That's what I was trying to do with my answer.

Comment: I voted up your answer which mean it is a good answer. I just wanted to share another thread which talk about something similar :)

Comment: This is an out of date answer - OpenID Connect is supported as of Feb 2016, please read: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/enterprisemobility/2016/02/23/for-developers-the-first-use-cases-of-the-converged-microsoft-account-and-azure-active-directory-programming-model-are-now-ga/

Answer (score 3):

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Live_ID#Support_for_OpenID

> Support for OpenID
>
> On October 27, 2008, Microsoft announced that it was publicly
> committed to supporting the OpenID framework, with Windows Live ID
> becoming an OpenID provider. This would allow users to use their
> Windows Live ID to sign-in to any website that supports OpenID
> authentication. There has been no update on Microsoft's planned
> implementation of OpenID since August 2009.

The project has been planned a few time ago, but it seems not to be implemented.

Comment: This is an out of date answer - OpenID Connect is supported as of Feb 2016, please read: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/enterprisemobility/2016/02/23/for-developers-the-first-use-cases-of-the-converged-microsoft-account-and-azure-active-directory-programming-model-are-now-ga/

Answer (score 1):

Additional Data found **[here](https://secure.shared.live.com/~Live.SiteContent.ID/~16.3.16/~/~/~/~/images/iconmap.png)**.

This [CSS Sprite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprite_%28computer_graphics%29#Sprites_by_CSS), which includes the OpenID logo in it,
would indicate that they (have/had) planned to include support within Windows Live.

Comment: Giving you a start. But you should seriously improve this answer, to give more self contained details, but the links. Site policies about _link only_ answers had been hardened meanwhile, and will be more obeyed now.

Answer (score 0):

OpenID Connect is supported by Microsoft Accounts (aka Windows Live ID, aka Microsoft Passport etc.) as of Feb 2016, please read: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/enterprisemobility/2016/02/23/for-developers-the-first-use-cases-of-the-converged-microsoft-account-and-azure-active-directory-programming-model-are-now-ga/