# Is Windows Live ID an OpenID Provider?

Tags: openid, single-sign-on, dotnetopenauth, windows-live-id

I've heard different things.  Seems like Microsoft [experimented with a beta service](http://winliveid.spaces.live.com/Blog/cns!AEE1BB0D86E23AAC!1745.entry), but I don't know if it's still available, or ever made it into production.

If Windows Live ID is an OpenID Provider, where is the endpoint?

Comment: Thanks Matt, although there's more to the story. Microsoft announced their support two years ago, then rolled out a CTP programme, but after that the picture becomes fuzzy.  It's not clear whether the service was decommissioned, which now appears to be the case.  If it did make it to RTM, then where are the production endpoints?

Comment: Question closed? Slip of the mouse perhaps?

Comment: Note that there are nice answers to this question at http://stackoverflow.com/a/6990971/377270

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.  Windows Live ID is *not* an OpenID Provider.  They use a proprietary protocol.  Ever since the close of their "beta" period, they've never announced plans to continue with it.

Comment: OpenID Connect is supported by Microsoft Accounts (aka Windows Live ID, aka Microsoft Passport etc.) as of Feb 2016, please read: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/enterprisemobility/2016/02/23/for-developers-the-first-use-cases-of-the-converged-microsoft-account-and-azure-active-directory-programming-model-are-now-ga/

Answer (score 3):

Check out [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg251990.aspx), I believe they use  OAuth (not OpenID).

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it really hasn't made it into production.

http://winliveid.spaces.live.com/ ([blog post permalink](http://winliveid.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!AEE1BB0D86E23AAC!1745.entry))