# OpenID alternative for MSN

Tags: php, openid, msn, cardspace

I want to support login with an MSN account but MSN doesn't support OpenID. Wikipedia says "Windows CardSpace (codenamed InfoCard), is Microsoft's **now-canceled** client software for the Identity Metasystem." So what is the alternative to OpenID for MSN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LiveConnect

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/live/hh561433

Comment: and how long this Live beast is going to Live ?

Answer (score 0):

This may answer your question:

[Windows Live supports Open ID](http://www.readwriteweb.com/archives/microsoft_windows_live_openid.php)

I believe any MSN account is already Windows Live

Comment: That article is from 2008 and according to wikipedia, no updates of when this will launch have been given since 09. How unlike Microsoft.

Comment: My bad - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056263/is-windows-live-id-an-openid-provider