# Using Microsoft OpenID (Windows Live)

Tags: google-app-engine, openid, windows-live-id

I have a small project on Google App Engine. And there I have a login system via OpenID, very basic, in accordance with the instructions in the documentation that exists in the same GAE.

In the documentation there is a list with the link of OpenID's like Yahoo and Google. I wonder what is the link to my app to authenticate using Windows Live OpenID.

Comment: Skip appengine auth. Make all pages public and authorize using google identity tookit which supports ms

Answer (score 0):

Windows Live did once support OpenID in 2008/2009, but that was canceled - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/4057119/282601

Answer (score 0):

You can register an app to authenticate against Windows Live or Work or School accounts at https://apps.dev.microsoft.com